# Is the MSFT AJAX Animation control the correct one to do this animation:

Tags: asp.net, ajax, animation, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I need to have a stack of 10 text lines, possibly div's, and insert a line arbitrarily somehere in the list.  In addition I'd like to fade in a highlight (for the new line) and fade out.

Is MSFT AJAX the correct tool to use for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are alternatives but as to whether this is the right one is subjective. Do you (and your colleagues) understand this implementation? Is it fast/light enough (i.e. are the users complaining)? If the answers are "Yes" then I'd say Microsoft AJAX is appropriate for this.

Comment: I'm the only developer and this is the first time I had this requirement. I'm open to learning the fastest most understandable implementation.

Comment: In that case, take a look at JQuery as well. Microsoft include it with ASP.NET MVC in preference to their own Ajax tools.

Comment: If you want to fade in you may prefer getting the line of text you want to show using a web service (via Javascript) and then using JQUERY to add the text (using .fadeIn())you get back from the web service. An UpdatePanel will just change the whole content with no effects

Comment: A web service may be a little overkill here but not a bad suggestion.